# add a label to a AtBeginSection slide

Tags: beamer, ref

I would like to put a `\ref` to one of the slides created with `\AtBeginSection`, is that possible?

In more detail, I abuse

```
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
\hspace{.8\textwidth}\includegraphics[width=.2\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{./symmetry_breaking.pdf}
}

\subsection[shorttitle]{long title with \texorpdfstring{$x^2$}{x2} \label{sym}
}

\beamertemplateshadingbackground{blue!01!white}{white}
```

to manipulate the background image on one `\AtBeginSubsection` slide. And as you see I *try* to put a label there, such that on the very last slide I can ask "Who spotted the mistake on slide `\ref{sym}`?"

Can I put labels on these auto generated slides?

(Alternatively, I'm also open to a workaround putting the label on the next slide and then do arithmetics to figure out the slide number before.)

**EDIT:**

At the moment my file looks (cut down to a MWE) like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>{}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\section{recap}
\subsection{what do we want}

\begin{frame}{what do we want}
  \begin{itemize}
      \item we want it all
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
  {~}\hspace{.8\textwidth}\includegraphics[width=.2\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{./symmetry_breaking.png}
}

\subsection[problem when you can zip]{problem when you can zip \label{sym}}

\beamertemplateshadingbackground{blue!01!white}{white}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{zipping solves everything}
  Lorem ipsum
\end{frame}

\subsection{1234}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{conclusion}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item headache ahead
    \item<2-> Bonus points for those who spotted the mistake on slide~\ref{sym}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

and it includes this image

[image: just an image]

(suffered in the conversion, but for what it's worth here, can be any image).

And I build with

```
rm -f pseyfert.aux pseyfert.toc pseyfert.snm
xelatex pseyfert.tex
xelatex pseyfert.tex
xelatex pseyfert.tex
```

The last slide looks like this

[image]

and should say "Bonus points for those who spotted the mistake on slide 3"

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but you don't need `\usepackage{graphicx}` with beamer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need a label for a single subsection, another approach could be to temporarily redefine your subsection frame -- of course this approach becomes cumbersome if you need labels for many subsections.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>{}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\section{recap}
\subsection{what do we want}

\begin{frame}{what do we want}
  \begin{itemize}
      \item we want it all
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begingroup
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
  \hspace{.8\textwidth}\includegraphics[width=.2\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-duck}%
}
\AtBeginSubsection[]{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>[label=sym]
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}
\subsection[problem when you can zip]{problem when you can zip}
\endgroup

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{zipping solves everything}
  Lorem ipsum
\end{frame}

\subsection{1234}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{conclusion}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item headache ahead
    \item<2-> Bonus points for those who spotted the mistake on slide~\ref{sym}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an ad hoc proposal. As Skillmon pointed out, there was an unnecessary `\expandafter`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>{}
    \ifx\mylabel\empty
    \else
      \label{\mylabel}
    \fi  
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}

\xdef\mylabel{\empty}
\begin{document}

\section{recap}
\subsection{what do we want}

\begin{frame}{what do we want}
  \begin{itemize}
      \item we want it all
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\xdef\mylabel{sym}
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
  {~}\hspace{.8\textwidth}\includegraphics[width=.2\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{./symmetry_breaking.png}
}


\subsection[problem when you can zip]{problem when you can zip}

\xdef\mylabel{\empty}
\beamertemplateshadingbackground{blue!01!white}{white}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{zipping solves everything}
  Lorem ipsum
\end{frame}

\subsection{1234}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{conclusion}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item headache ahead
    \item<2-> Bonus points for those who spotted the mistake on
    slide~\ref{sym}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a command with which you can choose to label the next subsection added with `\AtBeginSubsection` to your code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newif\ifLabelSubSec
\newcommand\LabelSubSec[1]
  {%
    \global\LabelSubSectrue
    \gdef\SubSecLabel{#1}%
  }

\AtBeginSubsection[]
{%
  \begin{frame}<beamer>{}
    \ifLabelSubSec
      \global\LabelSubSecfalse
      \label{\SubSecLabel}%
    \fi
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}%
}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}

\begin{document}

\section{recap}
\subsection{what do we want}

\begin{frame}{what do we want}
  \begin{itemize}
      \item we want it all
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
  {~}\hspace{.8\textwidth}\includegraphics[width=.2\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-duck}
}

\LabelSubSec{sym}
\subsection[problem when you can zip]{problem when you can zip}

\beamertemplateshadingbackground{blue!01!white}{white}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{zipping solves everything}
  Lorem ipsum
\end{frame}

\subsection{1234}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{conclusion}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item headache ahead
    \item<2-> Bonus points for those who spotted the mistake on slide~\ref{sym}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```